# ProFTPD Directory directives won't change user

Tags: proftpd

Here's my code, placed inside the proftpd.conf file.

```
<Directory public_html>
        GroupOwner ~   
        UserOwner www-data

        Umask 002 002
</Directory>
```

however, when I upload a file for testing, the user is still [user] instead of www-data.

Comment: What does [proftpd debug logging](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/howto/Debugging.html), debug level 10, show when you upload a file to that directory?  (And are you also using the `mod_vroot` module?)

Answer (score 0):

Probably, You didn't specify full path to public_html. Can you check this?

```
<Directory /full/path/to/public_html>
    GroupOwner ~   
    UserOwner www-data

    Umask 002 002
 </Directory>
```

Comment: ill check that out later, thank you!!! I'm going to kick myself if it's that simple :-)

Comment: No problem, when you check this, write about it.